# Increase the Android API level during app update

Tags: android, google-play

One of my existing launched app's minSdkVersion is 4, but now I want to provide an update , which minSdkVersion is changed to 5.

I have tried and upload to the market is okay, but what will happend when this update is really being rolled out?

What would happen to the user with device can't meet the requirement? Any side effect except they won't be able to install the app in the future?

Thanks.

Comment: @Padma, I am just testing the change, this is what I see in android market, under my app apk now: API Level： 5-16+

Comment: ya http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you "deactivate" old apk file in developer console - your app will we able for downloading only for API 5+. There will not be any effect for people with API 4 and already installed app.

If you keep both old and new apks in market in "active" state, then market will offer old one for people with API 4 and new one for people with API 5+. Also they will be offered to update your app.

When you add apk that supports less versions than old one, you will see this:

http://take.ms/E0SYg

Market resolve itself what apk to give user.

Comment: So do you mean, assume my existing old version is 1.0, so I an upload two 1.1 versions and activate together but they target different minSDK version?

Comment: No, you have to add new apk 1.1(minSDK = 5) and keep both -new and old-apks active. I'll add picture in 5 minutes