# Does Raising Min SDK Version Stop Users Downloading Any APK Android?

Tags: android, google-play

I know on iOS that if you raise the min iOS version on a release it means that any devices that are unsupported can still download the previous application that does support them.

Is there such a thing on Android or is at as soon as you release the new APK, the old one is removed from sale?

Comment: Updated `APK` for production is the final apk for all the devices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase the Android API level during app update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374317/increase-the-android-api-level-during-app-update)

Answer (score 0):

Whether the APK is removed or not depends on you - if you keep both versions active, GP will resolve which one should every user get - those with newer APIs will get updated one, those with old APIs will still be able do download previous version.

If you are really into "separate API", read [this article](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api.html).

**EDIT:**
I believe similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374317/increase-the-android-api-level-during-app-update).

Answer (score 0):

If you raise sdk version user with old sdk will not be able to download it. If user has already installed apk with old sdk and you update apk in gplay, he can use it while he doesn't uninstall it manually.