# Upload in google play store failed after changing project properties file

Tags: android, google-play

I had version 1.0 app which had Project target as android-10 in the Project.properties file. It was built successfully and uploaded in playstore...

Now i upgraded version to 2.0 and project target is changed to android-13

Now when i try to update the apk in Playstore.. it gives me error

"Upload failed..Failed to save your changes..Please try again"

I am using same package and keystore...only project.properties build target is changed

Manifest file still shows min-sdk-version=9 in both versions

I am able to install and update in my mobile device. But i cannot update apk in Playstore.

Please help know why i cannot update

Comment: No i build code in eclipse.. i have changed versioncode and build target in properties file. . Does changing build target has any issues in playstore?

Comment: Try to upload from different browser. like firefox .

Comment: I tried to do it from Firefox browser. But still same issue..i cannot upload apk

Comment: Please let me know ..is changing project build target from android 10 to android 13....effect apk upload in Playstore?

Comment: Actually look at this, no more solution [link]http://www.codeexplain.com/code/aca0d625-43e1-4cbc-a644-a39f0590a3e7
and only possible clearing cache of browser or using different browser or try again after sometimes.unfortunately , this issue is faced by many all over the world. sorry

Comment: Still my question .. does changing project target have any effect in this problem.. last version was using api 10 and this version is built with api version 13... but in manifest file i use minsdkversion as 9.... i have not done anything else.. i changed versioncode

Comment: not sure, but may be changing api version causes problem. U may contact   there -- 'contact us' link on the google play developer console help. It may useful

Comment: @user1235389  this may useful [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374317/increase-the-android-api-level-during-app-update]

Answer (score 1):

thank you all for supporting me. 
I was able to resolve it with another network connection. I feel some firewall issue was giving the error

Answer (score 0):

Have you change code version? Change version name is optional.

Comment: Previous app version build was 2.3.3 and now build is 3.2 ...because i changed the target to android-13 in project.properties file in eclipse.. manifest file uses-sdk minsdkversion is still 9