# Can the Play Store offer to download a previous version of an app if it's not supported in the device's Android version? (like iOS does)

Tags: android, google-play, backwards-compatibility

I want to publish a new version of my app that requires Android 4.4. I know I can do this adding the following to the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19"/>
```

*(19 is the SDK version for Android 4.4 according to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels))*

But I'd also want people with Android versions older than 4.4 to be able to download an older version of my app. How can I accomplish that, if at all possible? I know iOS does that automatically: If someone has an older iOS version than the required for an app, then an older compatible version 
of the app id downloaded instead. Does the Google Play Store have a similar "backwards-compatibility" feature?

Comment: No, Android doesn't has backward compatibility feature. You have to reduce your android:minSdkVersion and then use legacy libraries for the feature which removed in latest versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google Play release can contain multiple app bundles! When you prepare a release, apart from adding the new fresh and shiny app bundle (for the newer devices), also add the legacy app bundle from the app bundle library (for the older devices).

You can then verify which versions are active/inactive in app bundle explorer (click the version dropdown).

Google Play will manage which version to offer on which device on its own (prioritizing the ones with higher version codes, in case multiple are supported).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, user below version 4.4 will get the older version of your app.

> Just keep the older version in ACTIVE state in play store.

Comment: See this for more details: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11374600/4773277

Comment: Thank you. How do you set app versions to active or inactive? I can't find that in the Developer Console.

Comment: See this Screenshot 
http://take.ms/E0SYg

You can see this under app section in Google play developer console if you have an application with different MINIMUM SDK

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find it because it's not in the new "Manage versions" interface. Only in the old "APK" section, which will be removed shortly. I can't find a way to do that with the new interface.

Answer (score 1):

Use `gradle` instead this tag in `manifest.xml`

```
 minSdkVersion 16  
 targetSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ¿Any hint on how to modify this on an already generated APK?

Comment: @OMA I don't think this helps with keeping multiple versions available in store. But still, this is true: if possible, you should specify these in the Gradle build file instead of the manifest.