# Users able to download previous version of the app from google play store , even after the latest version is available

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

A latest version of the app has been released in the play store, but in the google play console statistics we can see that the users are able to download the previous version of the app. During which criteria is this possible? 
The target version has been changed and the previous version has been retained before rolling out the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that google play takes some time to Publish the new version to play store. Because it reviews each time you upload a new apk. The previous APk will be retained after the new apk goes live.

Comment: It has been almost a month or two releasing the application, but still in the google play console- statistics we can see the previous version of the app being downloaded by users.

Answer (score 0):

As well as installing from the Play Store, Google also helps with safe, offline P2P sharing. You can read more in [the blog post here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/offline-p2p-installs-beta.html)

I suspect these installs are coming from people sharing the app via Files Go by Google, ShareIT or Xender. If they appear in the Play Console statistics it means that the apps count as a Google Play install, and will be updated by Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to download the past version of any app if both the old and new version is in `ACTIVE` state in play store. See the example scenario in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374317/increase-the-android-api-level-during-app-update/11374600#11374600).

> If you "deactivate" old apk file in developer console - your app will
>   we able for downloading only for API 5+. There will not be any effect
>   for people with API 4 and already installed app.
>
> If you keep both old and new apks in market in "active" state, then
>   market will offer old one for people with API 4 and new one for people
>   with API 5+. Also they will be offered to update your app.

Comment: Thank You!!
I can see the previous version in the draft state and not in active( only the current version lists under the active ) in the play store console .Not sure how that is possible though.